# How to calculate percentage, Trigonometric functions in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Hello community I want to develop on calculator in Angular. In that calculator I am done with Mathematical calculation. I want Percentage (%) and Trigonometric functions and I don't know how to do this calculations.

**Here below is my code**

**app.component.html**

```
  <div class="row p-1 m-1">
  <div class="maindisplay">
      <input class="subdisplay" [(ngModel)]="displayValue" type="text" (keyup)="getValue(box.value)" placeholder="0" name="name" #box/>

      {{input}}
   </div>
  
</div>


<div class="buttons">
  <div class="row p-0 m-1">
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickNumber('Rad')">Rad</button>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickNumber('Deg')">Deg</button>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickNumber('x!')">x!</button>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickNumber('(')">(</button>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickNumber(')')">)</button>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="getPer()">%</button>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="allDataClear()">CE</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row p-0 m-1">
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickNumber('Inv')">Inv</button>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickNumber('sin')">sin</button>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickNumber('In')">In</button>
      <button class="btn-num btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickNumber('7')">7</button>
      <button class="btn-num btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickNumber('8')">8</button>
      <button class="btn-num btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickNumber('9')">9</button>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickOperator('/')">&divide;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row p-0 m-1">
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickNumber('&#x213C;')">&#x213C;</button>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickNumber('cos')">cos</button>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickNumber('log')">log</button>
      <button class="btn-num btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickNumber('4')">4</button>
      <button class="btn-num btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickNumber('5')">5</button>
      <button class="btn-num btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickNumber('6')">6</button>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickOperator('*')">x</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row p-0 m-1">
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickNumber('e')">&#x2091;</button>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickNumber('tan')">tan</button>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickNumber('root')">&#x221A;</button>
      <button class="btn-num btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickNumber('1')">1</button>
      <button class="btn-num btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickNumber('2')">2</button>
      <button class="btn-num btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickNumber('3')">3</button>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickOperator('-')">-</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row p-0 m-1">
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickNumber('Ans')">Ans</button>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickNumber('EXP')">EXP</button>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickNumber('xy')">xy</button>
      <button class="btn-num btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickNumber('0')">0</button>
      <button class="btn-num btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickNumber('.')">.</button>
      <button class="btn-primary btn-lg btn-primary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="getAnswer()">=</button>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" (click)="clickOperator('+')">+</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
  getValue(val: string) {
    this.input = val;
    console.warn(this.input)
  }

  clickNumber(num: string) {
    if (num == "0") {
      if (this.input != "") {    
        const lastNum = this.getLastOperand()
        if (lastNum.lastIndexOf("0") >= 0) return;
      }
    }

    if (num == "0") {
      if (this.input == "") {
        return;
      }
      const PrevKey = this.input[this.input.length - 1];
      if (PrevKey === '/' || PrevKey === '*' || PrevKey === '-' || PrevKey === '+' || PrevKey === 'cos') {
        return;
      }
    }

    this.input = this.input + num
  }


  getLastOperand() {
    let position: number;
    position = this.input.toString().lastIndexOf("+")
    if (this.input.toString().lastIndexOf("-") > position) position = this.input.lastIndexOf("-")
    if (this.input.toString().lastIndexOf("*") > position) position = this.input.lastIndexOf("*")
    if (this.input.toString().lastIndexOf("/") > position) position = this.input.lastIndexOf("/")
    if (this.input.toString().lastIndexOf("%") > position) position = this.input.lastIndexOf("%")
    if (this.input.toString().lastIndexOf("cos") > position) position = this.input.lastIndexOf("cos")
    return this.input.substr(position + 1)
  }

  clickOperator(op: string) {
    const lastKey = this.input[this.input.length - 1];
    if (lastKey === '/' || lastKey === '*' || lastKey === '-' || lastKey === '+' || lastKey === '%') {
      return;
    }
    this.input = this.input + op;    
  }

  calcPer() {
    var test = this.input;
    let lastKey = test[test.length - 1];
    if (lastKey === '%') {
      test = test.substr(parseInt(this.input) / 100);
    }
    this.resultPer = test;
  }

  calcFunction() {
    let formula = this.input;
    let lastKey = formula[formula.length - 1];

    if (lastKey === '.') {
      formula = formula.substr(0, formula.length - 1);
    }

    lastKey = formula[formula.length - 1];

    if (lastKey === '/' || lastKey === '*' || lastKey === '-' || lastKey === '+' || lastKey === '.') {
      formula = formula.substr(0, formula.length - 1);
    }
    this.result = eval(formula);
  }

  getPer() {
    this.calcPer();
    this.resultPer = this.resultPer;
  }

  getAnswer() {
    this.calcFunction();
    this.input = this.result;
    if (this.input == "0") this.input = "";
  }
```

This above code is my .ts file. I want only percentage and Trigonometric functions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide more context on what exactly you want to achieve, to calculate basic trig functions you can use `Math.sin()`, `Math.cos()`, `Math.PI` and so on ... Checkout [Math](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) This is not an Angular question more Javascript / [Typescript](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_es5_d_.math.html#sqrt1_2) related

Comment: @RicardoSanchez yes I want basic trig functions in angular please let me know some video tutorials or links which i can refer.

Comment: The way you do it in JavaScript

Comment: Checkout Codingtrain by Daniel Shifftman https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=znOBmOrtz_M that video is for Java but if you look He's channel for p5js you will find what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the percentage like this:

```js
function percentage(partialValue, totalValue) {
  return (100 * partialValue) / totalValue;
}
```

and all trigonometric functions using the built-in object Math.